# NGINX doesn't send original request body to upstream Node app

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, request, http-post

So I have a Node app which handles authentication behind Nginx. It is mounted on the /api/ path. When I send POST requests (that have form request bodies), the Node app doesn't receive the request body. Strangely enough, Nginx seems to receive the request body, but it doesn't seem to send it. Here's my configuration:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

log_format postdata $http_content_type $http_content_length $request_body;

upstream node-app {
      least_conn;
      server client1:8080 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
      server client2:8080 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}

upstream api-gateway {
      least_conn;
      server gateway1:4747 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
      server gateway2:4747 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
}

server {
      listen 80;

      location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_pass http://node-app;
      }

      location /api/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log postdata;
        proxy_pass http://api-gateway;
      }
}
}
```

I'm fairly new to Nginx, and I've thoroughly searched through Google, Stack Overflow, and the documentation. However I think I'm missing something. Can anyone help?

Comment: Let’s get debugging. What exactly do you observe on the Node.js side? Do you see the `$request_body` in the nginx log? What about the Node.js logs (if any)? Can you capture the problem with `tcpdump` maybe? Are you sure there is no other config file that might include directives like [`proxy_pass_request_body off`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_request_body) or [`proxy_pass_request_headers off`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_request_headers)?

Comment: Note: if nginx simply doesn’t send the bytes that constitute the message body, this ought to result in a request timeout, as Node.js should be waiting for `Content-Length` more bytes on the stream.